# How to best secure an API key in an iframe widget

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, security, api-key

I am developing a Javascript widget which will be embedded on client sites using an Iframe.

The widget code makes an API call to my backend service using an API key.  The API key for each different client will change.

At the moment, the API key is visible in the iframe src tag.  This means that it is easy for anyone to find the API key in the page source and for unauthorised users to make API calls.

What is the best way of securing API access in this situation?  I thought about using a client secret to encrypt the API key but that doesn't solve the problem as anyone who intercepts the key will still be able to be validated and make calls on the API backend.

There are a few questions online about this already but none with a detailed recommendation on how to go about the implementation.

My widget is HTML generated by a React.js application and the API backend is Ruby on Rails.

Comment: How are you determining different clients? Their IP address? It sounds like you basically want to log them in silently (maybe with their IP as their 'username') and assign them a JWT using rails and devise, then pass that back and forth between requests

Comment: As you have discovered a pure client side solution is not possible. A server side solution would be to call your api from the client site server with the api key to get an expiring token. Render the widget with the expiring token and send that to your api. Your api will validate the request using the token. Since the tokens have a finite life re-use is unlikely.  You could also give the tokens a finite number of uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps allows you to embed maps like https://mapsurl.com/?address=123Street&api_key=KDFJSDKFHSH

And the key is public. The reason it's safe is because they check the referrer URL. It can't be used on other websites because they will send the wrong referrer. So if you're creating a widget that people can embed in their sites, you can collect the URL from them that the embed will come from, and deny requests without that referrer.